# UITextField automatically begins editing mode

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have three `UITextFields` inside of a `UITableView` (3 separate rows). The first two are standard `UITextFields` which require text input but the third requires a data entry and is associated with a `UIDatePicker`.

Problem Statement:
When the screen loads, the third text field automatically begins editing and pops up the date picker. This is annoying. I just want the screen to wait for the user to begin input before doing anything. Please find below my `viewDidLoad` code. Your help / insight is much appreciated

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 910)];

expirationDatePicker.hidden = YES;
expirationDatePicker.date = [NSDate date];
[expirationDatePicker addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(changeDateValue:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self configureView];
}

- (void)configureView
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory 
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.detailItem cardName]];
    filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@".png"];
    NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    imgPickerButton.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
}
```

Attached is the screenshot taken immediately after the screen loads. You can see that the third text field has entered editing mode.

[image: Screenshot of textfield]

Comment: Is it in editing mode?  It looks like placeholder text....?

Comment: i do have default value for the text field, but why does that textfield go into editing mode? That is as soon as the screen loads, the cursor in on that textfield and the date picker becomes visible

Comment: Update: so I went ahead and added a line at the bottom of my viewDidLoad methods that says [expirationDateTextField resignFirstResponder] but then the textfield above goes into editing mode. I just want the screen to be completely visible without any textfield going into editing mode. Is that not possible?

Comment: Please post your code for `[self configureView];`.  Something **has** to be causing this....

Comment: Added the configureView method - this has me stumped!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - found the problem. In my tableviews I have custom UITableViewCells and in those custom cells, I for some reason had this method -

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

This was causing the textfield in the individual tableviewcells to automatically enter editing mode. Once I deleted this piece of code, it stopped doing that.

Answer (score 1):

One way I would do this would be to convert your date text field into a UIButton in a custom UITableViewCell and bring up the date picker when the user touches the button.

And when the user is done selecting the date, change the title of the button to reflect the date.